# AngularJS toggle ng source value on click

Tags: angularjs

I need some help about toggling ng-src between for example: image.jpg and image-active.jpg, but I have some issues because I need to active that with AngularJS.

This is the scenario: I called an API data from swagger and use ng-repeat to display images in html.

HTML

```
<div class="input-group interests-list">
     <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="interest in interests">
         <label>
             <div class="interest-icon">
                 <img src="{{interest.iconUrl}}" ng-click="changeImage()">
              </div>
              <input style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="{{interest.name}}">
                                {{interest.name}}
         </label>
      </div>
</div>
```

Service

```
this.getInterests = function () {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var req = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://customdealwebapi20180125110644.azurewebsites.net/api/Interests'
    }

    $http(req).then(function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Controller

```
      TestService.getInterests().then(function (data) {
        $scope.interests = data;
    });
```

and everything works fine

[image]

Now I want to achieve when someone click on the image, ng-src should be changed to image-active.jpg, and on the next click image should be changed to default value (image.jpg)

I know how to achieve through jQuery, like this

```
$(".interests-list .checkbox label input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
      var selectedIcon = $(this).val();

      if (this.checked) {
          console.log($(this).prev())
        $(this).prev().find("img").attr("src", "assets/img/home/icons/" + selectedIcon + "-active.png");
      } else {
        $(this).prev().find("img").attr("src", "assets/img/home/icons/" + selectedIcon + ".png");
      }
    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use ng-show

```
 <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="interest in interests" ng-init="interest.active = false">
     <label>
         <div class="interest-icon">
             <img ng-show="interest.active == true" src="active.png" ng-click="interest.active = !interest.active">
             <img ng-show="interest.active == false" src="other.png" ng-click="interest.active = !interest.active">
          </div>
     </label>
  </div>
```

or you can pass interest to your click function and set image src in your controller

```
<img src="{{interest.iconUrl}}" ng-click="changeImage(interest)">

$scope.changeImage = function(interest){

    if(checked)
        interest.iconUrl = "active.png";
    else
        interest.iconUrl = "other.png";
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share some fiddle regarding your answer? Does not work for me

Comment: If you add a working fiddle with your base code I would gladly update your fiddle my suggestions.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.